# Golang range through channel with odd behaviour when inplementing Heap's permutation algorithm

Tags: go, range, permutation, channel, heaps-algorithm

I was trying to implement [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) in go using channels. The code below is working fine when just printing the slices on the screen, but when using channels to delivery the arrays to a for/range loop on main function some unexpected behaviour occurs and the slices/arrays are printed in duplicity and not all permutations are sent. I thought that maybe i'm closing the channel earlier than the main function is able to print the results but i wouldn't expect that double print. Why is this happening and how can i make it work.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func perm(a []int64) {
    var n = len(a)
    var c = make([]int, n)
    fmt.Println(a)
    i := 0
    for i < n {
        if c[i] < i {
            if i%2 == 0 {
                a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]
            } else {
                a[c[i]], a[i] = a[i], a[c[i]]
            }
            fmt.Println(a)
            c[i]++
            i = 0
        } else {
            c[i] = 0
            i++
        }
    }
}

func permch(a []int64, ch chan<- []int64) {
    var n = len(a)
    var c = make([]int, n)
    ch <- a
    i := 0
    for i < n {
        if c[i] < i {
            if i%2 == 0 {
                a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]
            } else {
                a[c[i]], a[i] = a[i], a[c[i]]
            }
            ch <- a
            c[i]++
            i = 0
        } else {
            c[i] = 0
            i++
        }
    }
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    var i = []int64{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println("Without Channels")
    perm(i)
    ch := make(chan []int64)
    go permch(i, ch)
    fmt.Println("With Channels")
    for slc := range ch {
        fmt.Println(slc)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `permch` is modifying `a` at the same time as `main` is printing it, so your output is garbled.

I can think of three easy fixes:

1. Guard access to `a` with a mutex.
2. Put a copy of `a` on the channel:
3. Have some kind of return signal from main that it has printed and `permch` can continue. (don't really recommend this, but it works).

Number 2 is pretty simple:

```
a2 := make([]int64, len(a))
copy(a2,a)
ch <- a2
```

and is what I would recommend.

For #1, just declare a `var m sync.Mutex` as a package variable and `Lock` is anytime you read or modify `a`. This is a race condition though between the reader and the next modification, as you pointed out, so it probably isn't a good solution after all.

[fixed version on playground using #3](https://play.golang.org/p/GhNAAd4MSf)

Comment: Can you please show me how to implement #1 or #2? I think adding another channel to signal from main to the goroutine a little cumbersome. I've tried using builtin `copy()` and `make()` creating a new underlying array but i think the problem relies on main printing the array at the same time `permch` changes it. And i really don't know how to use mutexes since i can lock the part in permch that is changing the array but it do not guarantee that it will wait `main()` print the array.

Comment: And when i try to use Mutexes i am able to silence the race detector but not to get what i want which is the behaviour of the no channel version.https://play.golang.org/p/fSt9MfIyOi

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that slices are reference types, and are being accessed in multiple goroutines.  In `perm`, you're printing `a` directly as you finish processing it at each step.  In `permch`, you're sending `a` over the channel, but then immediate starting to modify it again.  Since each slice sent over the channel refers to the same underlying array, you have a race condition as to whether your next loop iteration alters `a` or your `Println()` call in main gets to that array first.

In general, if you're running into unexpected behavior in any program using goroutines, you *probably* have a race condition.  Run the program with the `-race` flag to see where.

**Edit:** also, closing a channel has no effect on a routine *reading* from the channel.  A channel can continue to be read until its buffer is empty, at which point it will start returning the zero value for that type instead.  Range loops over a channel will only terminate once the channel is closed *and its buffer is empty*.